# Приложение Angular 6 не запускается в IE11

Tags: angular, ie11, angular6

проблема: не запускается приложение на Ангуляре 6 в IE11.

[image: ошибка в консоле EI11:]

мой polyfills.js 
[image: ипортировал сюда всё что можно, т.к. почти отчаился...]

буду рад совету.

уважаемые коллеги:
1) первая ошибка находится в файле который не компилится, там поменял стрелочную функцию на обычную, о ней забыли. 2) [image: остаётся вот это], vendor и js файлы компилится в es5/. остаются вопросы: - такоё ощущение что подтягивается что-то после компиляции es5.  на прямую подключённых скриптов, которые всё бы сломали не вижу...[image: введите сюда описание изображения] полифилы подключил все что нашёл, мне столько не надо. подозреваю что это внутренняя ошибка, человека который писал код...либо же всё таки конфликт версий чего-то с чем-то... сегодня продолжаю 
страдать...
я джун прямо джун среди джунов, если написал откровенную чушь, то не серчайте, тыкните пальцем лучше.

фото к коменту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89288/discussion-on-question-by----angular-6---).

Comment: Итак, вчера просидел до потери пульса и жизненных сил:

Comment: Очевидно, смотрите строку 142465 файла vendor.js

Comment: (хотя вообще читать vendor.js занятие сомнительное, но надо ж с чего-то начать, раз IE11 не подхватил sourcemap)

Comment: @andreymal  к чему пришёл.

Comment: @andreymal  к чему пришёл.1)  подключил полифил import 'custom-event-polyfill';   и  import 'core-js/es7/array';  именно es7 , es6 был подключен, но почему не работал.  Теперь упёрся в  то что node_modules/point-cluster/quad.js    вот эта штука не билдится в es5 и explorer ругается на  см скрин вверху.  функция range